# How to get Pixel Position from DateTime Value on X-Axis?

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, position, pixel

**I'm trying to retrieve the pixel position on the chart of a DataPoint using its X Value (DateTime). 
I'm using this code after the Chart has been painted but I get a very large number:**

```
DateTime date = ... ; // DateTime of the DataPoint, I verified the date is correct and the chart contains it.    
var pixelsPosition = ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(date.ToOADate()); 
// Here pixelsPosition is a very large number, above 600 000.
```

These are the Chart settings:

```
Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

The Chart has around 2000 Points.

I'm using the same code to retrieve a pixel position of a DataPoint using the Y Value and it works. I'm sure it's a stupid problem but I can't figure it out.

Working code for the Y-Axis

```
double yValue = 100;
double pixPositionY = ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(yValue); // THIS WORKS
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I read that the method ValueToPixelPosition works only on Paint Events, I've tried to execute it on the Paint and PrePaint events but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem:

```
DateTime date;
int pixelPositionX = 0;
var point = Series[0].Points.Where(X => X.XValue == date.ToOADate()).FirstOrDefault();
var index = (point != null) ? Series[0].Points.IndexOf(point) : -1;

if (index > -1)
    pixelPositionX  = (int)ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(index + 1);
```

That gives me the correct position of the DataPoint on the screen. ValueToPixelPosition works if I pass the dataPoint index as parameter rather than the datetime value converted to OADate. I'm not sure if this is the right solution but it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but your solution is surely wrong. `ValueToPixelPosition()` requires a double value and not an index. Apart from that your workaround is very slow because it must search through all `DateTime` values on X axis.

To find out how Microsoft generates these strange X values I used ILSpy to disassemble `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.ni.dll` which can be found in `C:\Windows\assembly\....`

Here is the Microsoft code which converts `DateTime` into `double`:

```
// System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint
public void SetValueXY(object xValue, params object[] yValue)
{
    .......
    
    else if (type == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        _xValue = ((DateTime)xValue).ToOADate();
    }

    ........

    if (series != null && xValue is DateTime)
    {
        if (series.XValueType == ChartValueType.Date)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(((DateTime)xValue).Year, ((DateTime)xValue).Month, ((DateTime)xValue).Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            _xValue = dateTime.ToOADate();
        }
        else if (series.XValueType == ChartValueType.Time)
        {
            DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, ((DateTime)xValue).Hour, ((DateTime)xValue).Minute, ((DateTime)xValue).Second, ((DateTime)xValue).Millisecond);
            _xValue = dateTime2.ToOADate();
        }
    }
    .....
```

If you use `ChartValueType.Time` the double value on X axis is between 0.0  (for 00:00:00.000) and 1.0 (for 23:59:59.999)

I don't like the Microsoft code using a date from 1899.
This can be done easier:

```
int  s32_Millis = (((k_Time.Hour*60) +k_Time.Minute)*60 +k_Time.Second)*1000 +k_Time.Millisecond;
double d_OaTime = (double)s32_Millis / (24*60*60*1000);
double d_PixelPosX = ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(d_OaTime);
```